# Unique name functions in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, function

Is necessary to call wordpress functions(in template) unique names? I think if I call them simple names, they may conflict with plugins(if user will install in future them). Is it true?
Sorry for stupid question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should read all naming conventions here http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/the-wordpress-coding-standards-naming-conventions-and-function-arguments--wp-31683

Function Names

As mentioned earlier, if classes are nouns that ideally represent a single idea or single purpose, then their methods should be the actions that they are able to take. As such, they should be verbs - they should indicate what action will be taken whenever they are called.

Furthermore, the arguments that they accept should also factor into the name of the function. For example, if a function is responsible for opening a file, then its parameter should be a file name. Since our goal should make it as easy as possible to read code, then it should read something like "have the local file manager read the file having the following file name."

Use lowercase letters in variable, action, and function names (never camelCase). Separate words via underscores. Don't abbreviate variable names un-necessarily; let the code be unambiguous and self-documenting.

Of course, there are always worse - some developers resort to using single characters for their variable names (which is generally only acceptable within loops.)

Just as the Coding Standards state: Don't abbreviate variable names un-necessarily. Let the code be unambiguous and self-documenting.

Now, the truth is, code can only be unambiguous to a point.

**Anyway, the bottom line is to lower case your method names, avoid all camel casing, separate by spacing, and be as specific as possible when naming your variables and avoid duplicate names.**